# Pandas in Python 3.10 Cannot drop columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file which included some films info, and I want to remove column `director` and `cast`, but pandas told me KeyError.

Source Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv(r'titles.csv', sep='\t')

    info = df.info

    # print(df.head())
    # print(df.tail())

    # print('dftypes: ', df.dtypes)

    # null = df.isnull().sum(axis=1)
    #
    # print(null)

    # df2=df.drop(['director'],axis=1)
    print(df.columns)
    df.drop(labels='director', axis=1)
```

Columns in csv file:

```
show_id, type, title, director, cast, country, date_added, release_year, rating, duration, listed_in, description
```

Error info:

```
KeyError: "['director'] not found in axis"
```

I have tried to drop like the follows:

```py
df.drop(labels=['director', 'cast'], axis=1)

# or

df.drop(columns=['director', 'cast'])
```

Comment: what is the result of *df.columns*?

Comment: You need to assign back to df.    df = df.drop(columns=['director', 'cast'])

Comment: 1. `drop` is not `inplace`, 2. The separator is `, `(space after comma)

Comment: @Naveed The result is of df.columns is `Index(['show_id,type,title,director,cast,country,date_added,release_year,rating,duration,listed_in,description'], dtype='object')`

Comment: you see, you only have one column here, note the quotes

Comment: Can you [edit] to include a [mcve] with a sample of your input dataframe, like the output of `df.head()` so that we can better understand your problem?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh @jasonbaker neither `df=df.drop(...` or `inplace=True` would cause or prevent a `KeyError`, only affect the output

Comment: @G.Anderson Have you checked my 2nd point? The separator of his csv is `, ` while he uses `\t`.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh that's absolutely correct and the most likely cause of the issue, just wanted to point out that the first point is extraneous to the error in the question, since two people made it I didn't want the OP to get sidetracked into thinking that was related to the keyerror